# How to make entire row along with the checkbox in it, click and unclick when I anywhere click inside the table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a table

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="service_id[]" value="17" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td class="right">$175.00</td>
    <td>add 0 days to delivery</td>
</tr>
```

And jQuery

```
$('#tableSelect tr').click(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked') == true)
        $(this).find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    else    
        $(this).find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
});
```

My goal is to have the checkbox click ON and OFF as I click on **anywhere in the table row**.

However what I get is I can click anywhere on the table row to click and unclick, but when I click inside the checkbox itself, it does not register my click.

How can I make entire row and the checkbox in the row click and unclick when I click anywhere inside the entire table row, including entire the checkbox itself?

Comment: When you click the checkbox, it is immediately ticked as checked, then the click handler kicks in, sees that the checkbox is checked, and unchecks it. Or in the opposite order, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a click event to the `input`s and then use `stopPropagation` to prevent event bubbling.

```js
$('#tableSelect tr').click(function() {
  ele = $(this).find('td input:checkbox')[0];
  ele.checked = ! ele.checked;
});
$('input:checkbox').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableSelect">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="service_id[]" value="17" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class="right">$175.00</td>
    <td>add 0 days to delivery</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Incredible solution!

Answer (score 2):

You need to register `change event` also, so bind it like this:

```
$('#tableSelect tr').on('click change',function() {
    if ($(this).find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked') === true) 
        $(this).find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    else    
        $(this).find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Check the **below snippet**

```js
$('#tableSelect tr').on('click change', function() {
  if ($(this).find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked') === true)
    $(this).find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  else
    $(this).find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableSelect">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="service_id[]" value="17" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class="right">$175.00</td>
    <td>add 0 days to delivery</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="service_id[]" value="17" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class="right">$175.00</td>
    <td>add 0 days to delivery</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="service_id[]" value="17" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class="right">$175.00</td>
    <td>add 0 days to delivery</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="service_id[]" value="17" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class="right">$175.00</td>
    <td>add 0 days to delivery</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="service_id[]" value="17" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class="right">$175.00</td>
    <td>add 0 days to delivery</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="service_id[]" value="17" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class="right">$175.00</td>
    <td>add 0 days to delivery</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="service_id[]" value="17" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class="right">$175.00</td>
    <td>add 0 days to delivery</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="service_id[]" value="17" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class="right">$175.00</td>
    <td>add 0 days to delivery</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tableSelect tr *').click(function(e) {
  var $cb = $(this).parent('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]');
  var c = $cb.prop('checked');
  if (c === undefined)
    e.stopPropagation();
  else
    $cb.prop('checked', !c);
});
```